# My image show not found error but the link in terminal is able to locate the file

Tags: html, django, image

My image can't be load on page, the feedback shows

Not Found: /auctions/static/auctions/images/Artboard_1_copy.png
"GET /auctions/static/auctions/images/Artboard_1_copy.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3417

but when I ctrl and click on the link in feedback, I was able to open my image in my workspace.

This is my settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '6ps8j!crjgrxt34cqbqn7x&b3y%(fny8k8nh21+qa)%ws3fh!q'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'auctions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'commerce.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'commerce.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auctions.User'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]


import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type("text/css", ".css", True)
```

my html, load static was included on top of the file

```
<img class="image1" src="{{ listing.image }}">
```

my models.py

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="auctions/static/auctions/images", blank=True)
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:id>", views.item, name="item"),
    path("listing", views.Listing, name="listing"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register")
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I tried to add static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) and STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),] but doesn't works. Tried to add '.url' into {{ listing.image.url }} and doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'm answering here. You should refer to `url` property of your `listing.image` object rather than the object itself: `<img class="image1" src="{{ listing.image.url }}">`

Comment: Hi! I tried added <img src="{{ listing.image.url }}"> but still return 404 
"GET /static/auctions/image/no_image.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1941